# SD Card Reader RTS525A - Unassigned class [ff00]

Tags: 17.10, hardware, realtek, sd-card

I can't get my SD Card reader working on XPS 13 9360 running Ubuntu 17.10 kernel 4.13.0

lspci:

```
Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I tried suggestions from [here](http://www.linuxx.eu/2014/07/fix-unassigned-class-ff00-realtek.html) but still get error on make.

I found [this](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MFD_RTSX_PCI.html) but do not know how to really make use of it (I tried modprobe the other RT's without success).

Any suggestions? Thanks